# Typeahead/Bloodhound - number of results

Tags: jquery, typeahead, bloodhound

I have been using typeahead and bloodhound for a project and I find it really unintuitive as well as frustrating. Something that should take a second to do ends up in an hour of research.

Anyway i'm trying to alert the number of results into my bloodhound.

Here's my code so far

```
 var pisList = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                prefetch: {
                    url: "../Helper/LookUpPIs?list=" + $list,
                    cache: false
                }
            });

            alert(pisList.length);

            //Typeahead on project numbers
            $('.pis').typeahead({
                hint: true,
                higlight: true,
                minLength: 1
            },
                {
                    name: 'pis',
                    source: pisList
                });

            //Display project details distribution panel
            $('input.pis').on('typeahead:selected', function (event, selection) {
                var result = selection.match(/\((.*)\)/);
                getPiInformation(result[1]);
            });
            return false;
        }
```

Right now my alert return me undefined. I tried multiple variants but none of them were successful.

Let me know if you have a hint and thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently it isn't that easy

Comment: Up the post I need some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a dumb way but it works. I had to create a hidden field, loop through each result in datumtokenizer and increment the value.

```
var pisList = new Bloodhound({
                //datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                datumTokenizer: function (d) {
                    //count number of PIS found and put their ID in the field
                    $('#numberofPIs').val(Number($('#numberofPIs').val()) + Number(1));
                    return tokens;
                },
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                prefetch: {
                    url: "../Helper/LookUpPIs?list=" + $list,
                    cache: false
                }
            });
```

Probably not the best and cleanest way but it works

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(

    Object.keys(pisList.index.datums).length 

);
```